# How to programmaticallty create a <f:facet name="header"> for HtmlPanelGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

i am createing header for `<h:panelgrid>` from bean.
now this is jsf required code(if i written code in jsf page).

```
<f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Search Template ">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
```

My Problem is how to add this in bean file with below code.

```
HtmlPanelGrid mainPanel = new HtmlPanelGrid();
mainPanel.setColumns(1);
mainPanel.setStyleClass("searchtabtemplate");

HtmlOutputLabel htmlOutputLabelObj = new HtmlOutputLabel();
htmlOutputLabelObj.setValue(ApplicationConstants.NO_RECORD_FOUND);

mainPanel.getChildren().add(htmlOutputLabelObj);
```

I have tried with this code but where i have to use `facetTag` i dont get idea .

```
FacetTag facetTag = new FacetTag();
facetTag.setName("header");
HtmlOutputLabel htmlOutputLabel = new HtmlOutputLabel();
htmlOutputLabel.setValue("Search Template");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) superclass has a [`getFacets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFacets%28%29) method. Guess what it does :)

```
mainPanel.getFacets().put("header", htmlOutputLabel);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `HtmlOutputLabel` represents the `<h:outputLabel>` which is the wrong tool for the purpose. Use `HtmlOutputText` instead which represents `<h:outputText>`.